# Just echo query instead of var_dump

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can i change my code from `var_dump` to `echo` only?

Code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$myHost", "$myUser", "$myPass", "$myDB");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }


    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['username']);

var_dump($username);

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM exampletable where username = $username";
    if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            var_dump($row);
        }


    }
```

Because if i `var_dump($row);` i get always this:

```
'test@gmail.com' (length=16)
```

But i want echo only the username:) i am new with php sorry.

Thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code. You're already *partially* using the object-oriented style. You should commit to it fully and have consistency.

Comment: Note: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: print_r($username);

Comment: @tadman off: TC isn't want to make a bank application, here are only first steps in php. It's difficult to start from security I think )

Comment: @toor The first step when learning how to code database queries is how to code them correctly. There's zero benefit to taking shortcuts: They have a way of causing way more pain and trouble than they save in time. In many trades safety is the first thing they teach, and for a good reason. Tiny, innocent mistakes can be *expensive*.

Comment: `print_r($username);` is the same as var_dump and not echo

Comment: @tadman off: TC have the old manual, I think. And after a few years your suggests maybe will be outdated ) My opinion it's a better way to code something with mistakes at the first stages then coding nothing, but perfectly )

Comment: @toor I'm not the one making a huge issue out of these mistakes, I'm just flagging them and linking to resources that explain what to do to fix them. It's extremely important at the early stage to adopt good habits, to understand the safe way of doing things. I have been doing this for years as it's something the PHP community has historically not invested enough time in. If you want to step up and offer advice as well, that's great, but if you're saying this is not a big deal you're promoting indifference and ignorance.

Comment: @sarahn22 not the same, print_r is not show the lenght of the data. Try echo $username['username'], there [] contains the db column name, or please see the manual for the implode function

Comment: No idea how you are possibly getting just: `'test@gmail.com' (length=16)` when you `var_dump($row);` ... that just doesn't make any sense. What I think you mean is... you are only seeing the FIRST `var_dump($username);` because your query is actually failing, and not following into the `while` loop (there is no `else` on your `if` to show errors).

Comment: `mysqli_connect("$myHost", "$myUser", "$myPass", "$myDB");` If these are all variables then remove your quotes. :: `mysqli_connect($myHost, $myUser, $myPass, $myDB);`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is failing because you forgot to put quotes around `$username` in the query. It should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exampletable where username = '$username'";
```

Then in your loop you can do:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['somecolumnname'];
}
```

to see the contents of that column in every row that matches the username.

Answer (score 0):

[sarahn22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10364834/sarahn22)! I see you're a new contributor, so welcome to StackOverflow. :)

According to PHP MySQLi `fetch_row()` function [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), whenever you use it, you receive an array with each column as an index or null if no rows were found.

In that case, considering your username column would be the first column, you could get it by typing:

```
echo $row[0];
```

So, for better understanding, imagine the database table as:

```
username | first_name | last_name
---------------------------------
user01   | John       | Snow
```

This would be the results:

```
echo $row[0]; // Shows "user01";
echo $row[1]; // Shows "John";
echo $row[2]; // Shows "Snow";
```

Good luck on your new path in PHP learning. :)